# Can't fix the promises while using express validator

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can you please help me?

I'm stuck with these promises. I'm trying to validate username if it is already in use or not.

```
req.checkBody('username', 'Имя пользователя недоступно').custom(username => {
  return User.getUserByUsername(username).then(function(results) {
    return results[0];
  }).then(function(user){
    if (user) {
      throw new Error('Имя пользователя недоступно');
    }
  });
});
```

In order to check the users, I use the following function:

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
var query = {username: username};
return User.findOne(query, callback).then(function(user){
    if (user){
        return user;
    } else{
        return null;
    };
});
}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing exactly?

Comment: can you post your full code to page so it will give proper execution reference?

Comment: The issue is that the validator lets users register with same usernames. I\It doesn't work.